# How can I define startup applications with the Awesome Window Manager?

Tags: startup, window-manager, awesome

I've been reading as much as I can online, but none of it seems to work (i.e. changing `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`).

I've installed [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) window manager from the repos, and I log into it via GDM, and now I'd like to get it to start a few applications every time I log into the session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Starting from a template

First you'll need to copy the template rc.lua file into your home folder

```
mkdir ~/.config/awesome
cp /etc/xdg/awesome/rc.lua ~/.config/awesome/
```

### Defining applications to start

Now using `awesome - edit config` copy the following code at the bottom of your new rc.lua file

```
do
  local cmds =
  {
    "firefox",
    "xedit"
  }

  for _,i in pairs(cmds) do
    awful.util.spawn(i)
  end
end
```

In this example - firefox and xedit are run on startup.

An excellent wiki page describing this and much more can be found on [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome3#Autorun_programs)

Answer (score 12):

```
awful.util.spawn("conky")
awful.util.spawn("nm-applet")
```

Lines like these at the bottom of your .config/awseome/rc.lua will do the trick. If you want it simple. At least, that's what the [awesome-wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Autostart) calls simple.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [single_instance](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html#single_instance) or [once](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html#once) and pass them rules like this

```
awful.spawn.single_instance("firefox", awful.rules.rules)
```

Answer (score 0):

After an upgrade of Awesome, the solution:

```
awful.util.spawn("nm-applet &")
```

make it crash (return to the login prompt).

However, it works great with:

```
os.execute("nm-applet &")
```

Related ticket:  [awesome crashes when using awful.util.spawn() on startup](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/awesome/+bug/1176862)

Answer (score 0):

to prevent double launch:

```
do
  local autostarts =
  {
    "safeeyes",
  }

  for _,i in pairs(autostarts) do
    awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell(
      'ps -C '.. i ..' |wc -l',
      function(stdout, stderr, reason, exit_code) 
        gears.debug.dump(stdout)
        if tonumber(stdout) or 0 < 2 then
          awful.spawn(i)
        end
      end
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: [`awful.spawn.single_instance()`](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/libraries/awful.spawn.html#single_instance) should prevent double-launch so [George's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1171810/52781) seems like a better technique