# Fonts in menu are larger than they should be under Awesome WM

Tags: 11.10, fonts, awesome

I upgraded to oneiric ocelot, running awesome wm. Everything works, more or less, fine but one thing I've noticed is that now my menu fonts and my menu symbols are larger than I'd like them to be.

I used to set them in font settings, but now (for one I don't even know where font settings are anymore, I tried gnome-tweak-tool) the font-settings are gone? Surely I'm missing something.

My prime example is the program evince whose symbols are ginormous.

Any hints how to tweak it?

Comment: Simply from synaptic, then get a standard rc.lua and place it in ~/.config/awesome/ , that should do it.
Roland, the post you mentioned is not for awesome wm but addresses a general way for changing unity (and other) font settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume evince is looking like this:

[image]

I would use XFCE packages to help you on this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-settings
```

Then run the xfce daemon:

```
xfsettingsd
```

This will change the fonts to use GTK settings.

Run `xfce4-settings-manager` to change your fonts and icons:

[image]

Obviously you would want to run the daemon from login - see my linked answer on how to do this.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I define startup applications with the Awesome Window Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57264/how-can-i-define-startup-applications-with-the-awesome-window-manager)

Comment: You are amazing sir, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!! (I would vote up your answer but I'm new to askubuntu thus I don't have enough reputation :-/ )

Comment: Do you know if is there another way, not having to start the daemon? At the end of the day I use awesome to be very lightweight and don't want to keep another process running...

Comment: @Emanuele - 'fraid not - XFCE is very lightweight.  I presume there is a openbox equivalent.  Please share the answer if/when you find out.  Thanks!

Comment: @fossfreedom I've been trying out _lxappearance_ and apparently it works (at least for menu bars and so on)! Give it a shot, cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks - and also, if you're just experimenting and resources aren't an issue - one can also run `gnome-settings-daemon` to theme application fonts running in `awesome-wm` (but apparently, this doesn't include possible theming of application buttons; e.g. firefox keeps its (apparently) original forward and back buttons). Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: So… Does it work for anyone? [I get an impression that `xfsettingsd` works](http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/using-xfsettingsd-in-other-wm-td41433.html) only with pure XFCE with Awesome as its WM. Otherwise it prints `SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined`, and doesn't do anything except of hanging in memory. **UPD**: @Emanuele thanks, `lxappearance` worked!